# Horizontally Center TextBlock in Fullscreen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, fullscreen, center

I've got a **WPF Window** that I made fullscreen by assigning the following properties:

```
WindowState = Maximized
WindowStyle = None
Topmost = true
```

This works very good so far. Now I got two `TextBlocks` on my `Window` that I both want to center horizontally. Since it's fullscreen my idea was to just calculate the position from the screen's resolution. So I tried the following:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr handle = WinApi.getWindowByName("myWindow");
    int height = Screen.FromHandle(handle).Bounds.Height;
    int width = Screen.FromHandle(handle).Bounds.Width;
    textBlock1.Margin = new Thickness(width / 2 - textBlock1.ActualWidth, height / 10, width / 2 - textBlock1.ActualWidth, height / 1.5);
    textBlock2.Margin = new Thickness(width / 2 - textBlock2.ActualWidth, height / 10, width / 2 - textBlock2.ActualWidth, height / 3);
}
```

`WinApi` is a class from me that encapsulates `WinApi`. I'm using `ActualWidth` since the width of both `TextBlocks` is set to `Auto`. Getting the screen's dimensions works fine so far. However the textBlocks are not rendered exactly in the middle of the screen. I know that for sure because they are both rendered at different horizontal positions.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="test" Height="300" Width="300" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" Background="#FF0000DC" Foreground="#FFF4FCF8" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockHeader" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White" Foreground="#FF0C04DB" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="Header" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="text"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I made a screenshot of how it looks like: http://www11.picfront.org/token/UAhu/2013/06/02/2140894.png
In the picture you can clearly see that the two Textblocks are not equally aligned.

Comment: getting a 404 on that URL.

Comment: Try this one http://www.picfront.org/d/8YWz

Comment: See update to my answer and please post XAML/code if yours still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're swimming upstream. Why not just use WPF's [layout system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx)?

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Foo</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Bar</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Update after seeing your screenshot:**

You must have something wrong with your XAML, but I can't say what because you've not posted it. This works perfectly for me:

```
<Window x:Class="SO16881549.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Topmost="True">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Title</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">This is a test-text!</TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't show my TextBlocks centered. They are still on different positions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Your text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```